# How to find ∂u/∂x and ∂u/∂t of this?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, chain-rule

We are given $$u(x, t) = f(x − t*u(x, t))$$

How do we determine
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \quad\text{and}\quad \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}? $$

Attempt:

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = f'(x-t*u(x,t))$$

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = -u(x,t)*f'(x-t*u(x,t)) $$

Help appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$
u(x,t)=f(z) 
$  with $z=x-tu$. Using the chain rule and supposing that $x, t$ are independent variables ( so that $\frac{\partial t}{\partial x}=0$), we have:

$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=
f'(z)\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=f'(z)\frac{\partial (x-tu)}{\partial x}=
$$
$$
=f'(z)\left(1-\frac{\partial t}{\partial x}u-t\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)=f'(z)\left(1-t\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)
$$
that gives
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\left[1+tf'(z) \right]=f'(z)
$$

so we have:
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{f'(z)}{\left[1+tf'(z) \right]}=\frac{f'(x-tu)}{\left[1+tf'(x-tu) \right]}
$$

You can do the same for the derivative with respect to $t$

Comment: Hi Emilio. I'm lost at the first line. How is ∂u/∂x = f'(z)(1-t∂u/∂x)?

Comment: the term $1-t\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}$ must be a factor after $f'(z)$

Comment: you derivative is not true.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner It certainly is.

Comment: I added something....

Comment: When I do it w.r.t 't', I get 0. I don't understand how to differentiate inside the functions. I understand when we have something like f(x,y) = x^3+3y^2 then ∂f/∂x = 3x^2 and ∂f/∂y = 6y. But when we have something like f(x,y) = u(something) I'm really lost :/

Comment: @EmilioNovati It's ok, I understand now but need lots more practice, thanks mate :)

Comment: with the same $z$ as in the answer, we have: $\frac{\partial z}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}-\frac{\partial t}{\partial t}u-t\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=0-u-t\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}$  and you can do from this.

Answer (score 1):

given $$u(x,t)=f(x-tu(x,t))$$ then we get by the chain rule
$$\frac{\partial u(x,t)}{\partial x}=f_x(x-tu(x,t))(1-tu_x(x,t))$$
and
$$\frac{\partial u(x,t)}{\partial t}=f_t(x-tu(x,t))(-u(x,t)-tu_t(x,t))$$

Comment: Hi Dr. Sonnhard. I added the answer above and it looks different to this, I'm unsure how to evaluate.

Comment: you must use the chain rule and you forgot this

Comment: I don't understand why you differ between $f_t$ and $f_x$. From my perspective both of them are equal to $f'$

Comment: no that is not true, since f is a function of $x$ and $t$

Comment: no $f$ is clearly a function in one variable.

Comment: the Argument of f is $x-tu(x,t)$ i Count $x$ and $t$

Comment: okay.. Lets regard $g:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, x \mapsto x$. even if I write $g(x+2t)$ this doesn't change that $g$ is a function in only one variable...

Answer (score 1):

By the chain rule,

$$\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}=f'(x-tu(x,t))\mathbf{\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(x-tu(x,t)\right)};$$ Can you conclude and to the same for $\partial u/\partial t$?

Comment: Hi dlc, I added the answer above, and it looks somewhat different to this.